# Get opposite of manage.py inspectdb / print sql created from models

Tags: python, django

To get the django models from my sql database I can do:

```
$ python manage.py inspectdb
```

How would I get the sql tables that should be created from my models in django 2.1? I'm not looking for anything beside it literally printing out the sql create table syntax. No creating tables or anything else. I've tried using `sqlmigrate`, but could figure out how to get that to print the sql. Any help would be great here.

Comment: `python manage.py sqlmigrate app_label migration_name` You will have to create the migration first.

Comment: @KlausD. could you please explain what you mean by "I will have to create the migration first". Is there no replacement for `sqlall` in the current version of django? I don't need to create a migration or anything.

Comment: @David542 In short, you want the SQL schema of your models, right?

Comment: @JPG correct just the sql

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
python manage.py sqlmigrate <your_app_name> <migrations_number_like_0001>
```